# What is the biological advantage of bilaterity?

Tags: evolution, bilateria

I was wondering why there were so many bilateral species (under the bilateria clade) in comparison with the cnidaria clade. I have two or so questions:

- Am I (or are we) unaware of the diversity and population of the cnidaria clade, so I can't say that bilaterity seems to be prefered by the natural selection?
- Is bilaterity an advantage only on earth and not in water (where I think most of the cnidaria clade is (jellyfishes)).
- If the answer to the last question is true, why is bilaterity an advantage on earth and less an advantage in water, and why is the contrary true for "unilaterality" (I don't know what is the word to describes the cnidaria clade).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Interesting question and I look forward to seeing what answers you get, but unfortunately I suspect it may not be answerable. ——— Jellies have radial symmetry.  ——— You may want to take the time to check out the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] effectively questions on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: keep in mind cnidaria are bilaterally symmetrical, they are just symmetrical in other ways as well. Then you have sea cucumbers which may have evolved bilateral symmetry twice independently.

Answer (score 1):

Bilateria, as a clade (all animals, excluding sponges, cnidaria, comb-jellies, and placozoans) is monophyletic, and as such, originated from a single species that was bilaterally symmetrical. Sometimes the explanation for a particular trait involves ancestry, and if an innovation is advantageous, it tends to spread. Along with this group came advances in the central nervous system, and digestive systems. It is advantageous to put senses up front, in the head, with the mouth. Having a tube-like digestive system, with a mouth at one end, a gut in the middle, and an anus at the other end, turned out to be efficient. Cnidaria (and other non-bilaterians) are not nearly as diverse as bilaterians, and most bilaterians are marine. So the bilateral advantage holds both in water, and on land.